# How to serialize a Map<String, String> to JSON object without backslashes

Tags: java, json, kotlin, serialization, backslash

I have a kotlin data class like this:

```
data class CompanyPreview(
val names: Map<String, String>,
val content: String
) : JsonSerializable
```

In my function where I return this I don't do anything special, I just fetch the names and content from database and return it to the response

```
return CompanyPreview(objectFromDB.names, content)
```

The problem is that I get the response like this for array fields:

```
names: {
"someField": "Test string",
"prices": "[\"200$, 300$\"]"
},
content { ... }
```

Is there a way I can serialize the prices so it does not include the backslashes ?

Comment: `names` should probably not be a `Map<String, String>`?

Comment: Looks like your names contains only Strings, so the escaped quotation marks `\"` exist already on the Java side. The solution is to look where they get created. Probably a toString function on a Collection, as the `[ ]` suggest.